# DocuSign: remove mobile post signing screen

Tags: docusignapi

When sending a document to a user via email (originating from the api) if that user clicks the link and signs on a mobile after they have completed the signing process the user is show a screen.  that i believe is called DocuSignComplete (the url is https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/DocusignComplete.aspx?ti=)

i can not see a setting in the Captive Sign Resource xml file that would disable this screen. i could also not find anything on google.

here are the only 2 relevant entries i can see,

```
<data name="DocuSignComplete_DisplayViewDocumentLinkAndIcon">true</data>
<data name="DocuSignComplete_ShowSocialNetworks">true</data>
```

i Dont want to disable sections, i want the user to be redirected to the redirectURL directly after completing

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, if DocuSign is sending out emails to the recipient chances are you are performing 'remote signing'. If that is the case, create a custom brand used for signing -> landing pages -> there are various scenarios listed where you can specify the user is directed to upon completion/decline/timeout/etc. Sounds like you want to put a custom URL for On Complete.

Comment: You are right i am doing remote signing, I have set the landing page urls. the page that is showing has a button label "exit" when the user taps that button they are taken to the "Sign Complete" landing page i have defined.